# How to access an element on cv::gpu::GpuMat matrix using CUDA and OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, matrix, cuda, gpu

I'm working on a project which implement face detection algorithm on CUDA platform.

Currently I'd to access an  element on `GpuMat` instance.

I have tried the following conventional methods:

1. Trying to make induction from `cv:Mat`,  `GpuMat` doesn't have a `<T>.at` method.
2. I have tried using `CV_MAT_ELEM` , I receive an error.

Here is my code on **FaceDetection.cu** file:

```
        int DetectFacesGPU(cv::gpu::GpuMat * sumMat ,cv::gpu::GpuMat * qSumMat , float factor)
            {
                //
                int i = CV_MAT_ELEM(*sumMat,int ,0,0); 
                //
```

I receive an error

```
Error   29  error : expression must have class type C:\Users\Shahar\Dropbox\OpenCV2.3\OpenCV2.3\FaceDetectionLatest\FaceDetectionCuda\FaceDetectionLatest\FaceDetection.cu  139
```

Comment: Many people doing OpenCV GPU use ArrayFire to fill-in-the-blanks on missing functionality.

Comment: Can you get me an example for doing that

Comment: Is there any elegent way accessing pixels on the gpu::mat  ? thanks for answer

Answer (score 3):

You have to download it to a `cv::Mat` and then access it with the standard way.

I think downloading it is as simple as:

```
cv::Mat mat;
sumMat->download(mat); // or something like that.
```

Comment: No, I'd like to check the value on the gpu platform. E.g during Cuda code

Comment: No, you can't. But please don't blame me for that. Maybe you can only download a submatrix, to make it faster, but it is anyway just a debug trick. You should not use this approach as a base for your algorithm.

Comment: hahah .... @vasile I don't blame you for that...That's what happened when your  first language is not English.

Answer (score 0):

From the definition of `CV_MAT_ELEM`, `CV_MAT_ELEM(*sumMat, int, 0, 0);` is expanded to:

```
*(int*)CV_MAT_ELEM_PTR_FAST(*sumMat, 0, 0, 4));
```

and in turn expanded to:

```
*(int*)(assert ( 0 < (*sumMat).rows && 0 < (*sumMat).cols ),
               (*sumMat).data.ptr + (size_t)(*sumMat).step*0 + 4*0);
```

Assuming that your `DetectFacesGPU` function is defined as a device code, the above statement is faulty because you can't dereference `sumMat` in device code. By doing so you're accessing host memory from device code. You have to be careful because *`GpuMat` class itself* is allocated in host memory. It is *only the actual matrix data* that is allocated in device memory.

So `GpuMat` class itself is, in general, not passed to kernel. To access individual pixels of `GpuMat` in kernel, you have to pass the pointer referencing the actual matrix data (which is in device memory) to the kernel and do pointer arithmetic on that pointer.